Bad car seats. Which are interchangeable?
For a Scion tC, '05.
Looking to find similar model seats that will fit the railing and electrical connection.
(Many, many mechanical parts like alternator, starter, water pump, etc. are interchangeable between Scion, Camry, Corolla, Solara, even Rav 4's./)
So any chance I could successfully swap out more comfortable seats from these other models, from the junkyard? With the correct and compatible airbag connections, right fit for bolt patterns, etc.?
Already tried padding, seat wedges, whatever- you name it. The current stock seats are just hard on the back, promote rounded shoulders, just not great ergonomically.
If the junkyard idea won't fly, anything else you can recommend I try instead?

If you don't find anything that fits from another vehicle (and chances are, if it does fit - it will likely be the same low quality) you may want to consider aftermarket sport seats (e.g. Recaro or some more budget brands).
